# "void" is Incompatible with parameter of type "void*"

Tags: c++, visual-c++, glfw

I'm trying to add a void function as a parameter so that I can put other functions inside my code to optimize, and reduce if statements, but I'm somewhat of a newbie, and am a little confused as to the proper parameter to set it as.

```
static void standardKeyPressRelease(GLFWwindow* window, int key, int action, void* fun, bool press)  {
    int keyname = glfwGetKeyScancode(key);
    if ((key == keyname && action == GLFW_PRESS) && press) {
        fun;
    }
    if ((key == keyname && action == GLFW_RELEASE) && !press) {
        fun;
    }
}
void key_callback(GLFWwindow* window, int key, int scancode, int action, int mod) {
    //if (key == GLFW_KEY_ESCAPE && action == GLFW_PRESS) {
    //    glfwSetWindowShouldClose(window, GL_TRUE);
    //}
    standardKeyPressRelease(window, GLFW_KEY_T, action, glfwSetWindowShouldClose(window, GL_TRUE), true);
}
```

I've attempted to static_cast and dynamic_cast it, but I'm not entirely sure if that's right.

Comment: Can you explain, in your own words, what you expect "`fun;`" to do, in this function? This doesn't do whatever you think it does, for the very simple reason that this does absolutely nothing at all, whatsoever, and a C++ compiler will see this, go "LOL!", and ignore it completely. It seems like you're trying to guess what the correct C++ syntax would be, to do something. C++ is just too complicated to be learned by trial and error. If you're not sure about how to do something specific in C++, then ask ***about that*** instead of posting code with unclear purpose, and a compilation error.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik, I did ask "how do I put a function as a parameter, so that I can input my functions inside my code" I also said that I was new "I'm somewhat of a newbie, and i'm a little confused as to the proper parameter" so everything you said had already been iterated by me, But looking back at my code, it doesn't help you understand what I wanted, where I have ```standardKeyPressRelease()``` at the bottom is the function that I want to dynamically put into the code, as well as the possibility to change the function (where I have ```void* fun```) later if I put down a separate key.

Comment: The issue is not how to "put a function as a parameter". Trying random casts will not work. C++ is just too complicated, as I said. Step 1 is to actually learn how to specify a function or a callable object, as a parameter. Step 2 is then passing it in, later. Sounds like re-focusing on C++ fundamentals, first, would work better than attempting to figure out how to use a relatively complicated software library like glfw. This is explained in every textbook that covers the C++ library and function objects; unfortunately Stackoverflow does not really work as a replacement for a C++ textbook.

Comment: There are many things wrong with this code, and it's hard to tell, **step by step**, how you intend for it to work.

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do is declare `fun` to be a function pointer in your function declaration, then `fun` can be called as a function. It looks like you want `fun` to be a function that takes no arguments and returns void, so the declaration would be `std::function<void()> fun`:

```
static void standardKeyPressRelease(GLFWwindow* window, int key, int action, std::function<void()> fun, bool press)  {
    int keyname = glfwGetKeyScancode(key);
    if ((key == keyname && action == GLFW_PRESS) && press) {
        fun();
    }
    if ((key == keyname && action == GLFW_RELEASE) && !press) {
        fun();
    }
}
```

Now you want to pass a function that takes a couple of input arguments into this function. To do this you will need to bind those arguments to the function you're calling in a function object that takes no arguments. The simplest way to do this is with a [lambda function](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda):

```
[&](){glfwSetWindowShouldClose(window, GL_TRUE);}
```

So, you can then pass this lambda into your function:

```
standardKeyPressRelease(window, GLFW_KEY_T, action, [&](){glfwSetWindowShouldClose(window, GL_TRUE);}, true);
```

Comment: This is not going to work. The OP will get confused by even more incomprehensible errors.

Comment: The first 1/2 of this answer is correct. But the 2nd 1/2 won't work, because a *capturing* lambda is not convertible to a function pointer, only a *non-capturing* lambda is convertible.  Change the `fun` parameter to be either a templated Callable type or a `std::function<void()>`, then both types of lambdas can be used.

Comment: I am now getting an error that states ```no suitable conversion function from "lambda []()->void" to void(*)()" exists``` I apologize but I am still learning the different formats of lambdas from Java to c++, so this issue is also a little out of my hands.

Comment: forgot about the capturing lambda restriction. See updated answer (as per @RemyLebeau suggestion)

Answer (score 0):

```
void standardKeyPressRelease(int key, int GLFWkey, int action, int GLFWaction, std::function<void()> fun) {
    if (key == GLFWkey && action == GLFWaction) {
        fun();
    }
} 
void key_callback(GLFWwindow* window, int key, int scancode, int action, int mod) {
    standardKeyPressRelease(key, GLFW_KEY_T, action, GLFW_PRESS, [&]() { glfwSetWindowShouldClose(window, GL_TRUE); });
}
```

Thanks to the other answers, and a little help, This has currently fixed the issue I was having. By changing it to `std::function<void()> fun` I even optimized it a little bit, so I wouldn't have two if statements, and also removed the bool `press`